# Perl: How to sync files with ftp server

Tags: ftp, perl, synchronization

I'm looking for a way to sync a local folder with a remote folder that is only accessible with FTP.

Is this possible in Perl or is it possible by calling a System-command in Perl ?

I'm in a Windows 2008 environment so no Linux applications possible

Answer (score 3):

You could roll your own using [Net::FTP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Net::FTP) but helping you with that would require code from you.

You could compile [sitecopy](http://www.manyfish.co.uk/sitecopy/) using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/). It works.

But, I would first go ask at [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) before committing to either course of action.

Answer (score 1):

A very powerful cross-platform application `wget` might help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a *nix system I suggest [RSYNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). But as you require a Windows solution try [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp).

> In technical terms, DeltaCopy is a
>   "Windows Friendly" wrapper around the
>   Rsync program, currently maintained by
>   Wayne Davison. "rsync" is primarily
>   designed for Unix/Linux/BSD systems.
>   Although ports are available for
>   Windows, they typically require
>   downloading Cygwin libraries and
>   manual configuration. — [What is DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)